# What is the difference between response from a server in bytes and in unicode?

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests, utf

I'm using python's requests library and from it the response can be obtained either in bytes or In Unicode. I want to the difference between them, when to use the response in Unicode or in bytes. And how to interconvert them.

```
data=requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&api_key=f202d54c37859d31e6fb579da4c3b408&format=json').text

data=requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&api_key=f202d54c37859d31e6fb579da4c3b408&format=json').content
```

what is the difference between either of them and when should use one over other?

Comment: Why are you trying to unpickle a tar?

Comment: You'd might get a workaround by using `dummyfile = io.BytesIO(file.read())`?

Comment: You can't just use `tarfile` like everyone else?

Comment: My question is abt their use cases.?

Comment: If u could elaborate it would be helpful

Comment: Remember you can use .json() too to get a dictionary right away. Docs here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response